# (node)warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected.11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to incease limit

Tags: node.js, postgresql, memory-leaks, eventemitter

I`m fresh to node.js. I`m testing a node.js project.And I meet some problems. At first , I connect severals postgresql database, every goes well.But after added two new connection to postgrelSql database, here is my connection code:

```js
var dbConfig = config.dbOrderV2;
exports.ORDERV2 = {};
exports.ORDERV2 = new Sequelize(dbConfig.dbname, dbConfig.username, dbConfig.password, {
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  host: dbConfig.host,
  port: dbConfig.port,
  timezone: '+08:00',
  logging: undefined,
  pool: {
    maxConnections: dbConfig.pool
  }
});

var dbConfig = config.dbPay;
exports.PAY = {};
exports.PAY = new Sequelize(dbConfig.dbname, dbConfig.username, dbConfig.password, {
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  host: dbConfig.host,
  port: dbConfig.port,
  timezone: '+08:00',
  logging: undefined,
  pool: {
    maxConnections: dbConfig.pool
  }
});
```

I run up the project and here is the warning:

```js
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at process.addListener (events.js:239:17)
    at ConnectionManager (/Users/yangtao/Documents/code/zhike/data_import_export/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:45:11)
    at new ConnectionManager (/Users/yangtao/Documents/code/zhike/data_import_export/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:13:29)
    at new PostgresDialect (/Users/yangtao/Documents/code/zhike/data_import_export/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/index.js:12:28)
    at new Sequelize (/Users/yangtao/Documents/code/zhike/data_import_export/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:213:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yangtao/Documents/code/zhike/data_import_export/src/common/dbs.js:185:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yangtao/Documents/code/zhike/data_import_export/src/common/global.js:21:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yangtao/Documents/code/zhike/data_import_export/dummyWorker.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
```

Can anybody help me to fix it up? thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13806 check this

Comment: that one did`not work for me, but this help me: 'process.setMaxListeners(0);',still, thanks a lot. : D

Comment: glad you fixed it ^_^